# How can limit the number of lines and characters by line in a TMemo component

Tags: delphi

I Need  limit the number of lines and characters by line in a TMemo component.

example a i like to do something like this :

```
Memo1.MaxLines:=20;
Memo1.CharsByLine:=80;
```

how i can do this in delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some undelrying problems...like what would happen if you assign the memo1.lines.text value with a large block of text?  Would you want errors to occur, the data to be forced down to 80 chars/line...

It sounds like you need a word processor control instead of a TMemo.  Check out http://www.TRichView.com or http://www.wpcubed.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an easy way to do this, I have set a OnKeyPress Event before that attempts to limit it (I don't know if it handles pasting in text)

```
procedure AddressMemoOnKeyPressEvent(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
   i, lineCount: Integer;
begin
   with Sender as TMemo do
   begin
      if (Key <> #13) and (Key <> #8) and (Length(Lines[CaretPos.Y]) >= MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE_IN_MEMO) then
         Key := #0;

      lineCount := 0;
      for i := 1 to Length(TMemo(Sender).Lines.Text) do
      begin
         if (TMemo(Sender).Lines.Text[i] = #13) then
            Inc(lineCount);
      end;

      if (Key = #13) AND (Key <> #8) AND (lineCount >= MAX_LINES_PER_MEMO - 1) then
         Key := #0;

      // if we got past the last line, no key can be entered...
      if (CaretPos.Y >= MAX_LINES_PER_MEMO) then
         Key := #0;
   end;
end;
```